# Does Ubuntu Touch ship with proprietary code?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, proprietary, open-source

Does *Ubuntu Touch* (i.e., the system and pre-installed apps) contain proprietary code? Or is it 100% FLOSS?

Answer (score 2):

ubuntu-touch is licensed under the GPL v2. I guess the kernel will include some proprietary blobs for drivers (as does the Ubuntu desktop distribution). The core applications are also released under the GPL. Pre-installed apps, will probably depend on the device. E.g. the Telegram client is FLOSS, but the server side is not (yet?) released under a FLOSS license.
My bq acqaris 4.5 came pre-installed with a game (cut the rope -free) which is obviously proprietary...but then again contrary to other phones you can remove whatever does not fit your taste without the need to resort to "rooting application" of unknown origin.